# Go Fish Trouble: All Function Skipped When I Run the Game (Python)

Tags: python

I can't seem to get the my Go Fish game to work--I'm having trouble with random.choice, and for some reason nearly all of my functions are skipped when I run the game. I also get a "local variable referenced before assignment" error when I run ask_comp(). Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
from random import randint
from random import choice

cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
deck = cards * 4

user = []
comp = []

point_value = {"2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10, "J":11, "Q":12, "K":13, "A":14}

def draw_card() -> str:
    """draws a single card and removes it from deck"""


    card = deck[randint(0, len(deck)-1)]
    deck.remove(card)

    return card

    if deck == 0:
        print("Deck is out of cards")
        return None

def deal_cards():
    """deals cards for user and computer"""

    for i in range(7):
        user.append(draw_card())
        comp.append(draw_card())

    user.sort()
    comp.sort()


def go_fish(hand:list) -> str:
    """Prints go fish and draws a card"""

    print("Go fish!")

    card = draw_card()

    hand.append(card)
    hand.sort()

    if hand is user:
        print("Now adding " + card + " to you hand.")
    else:
        print("The computer has drawn a card.")

    return card



def give_cards(giver:list, taker:list, card:str) -> tuple:
    """Passes cards from one hand to another"""

    print("Transfering card " + card)

    while( card in giver ):
        giver.remove(card)
        taker.append(card)

    taker.sort()
    
    return giver, taker


def display():
    """Display the contents of the hands"""
#how do and what do here?
    print("Your cards are: ", user)
    print("The computer has ", len(comp), " cards.")
# could this be better for the user?
    

def play_again() -> bool:
    """prompts user if they wish to play again"""

    while(True):
        
        resp = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ")
        resp = resp.upper()
        
        if resp == "Y":
            user.clear()
            comp.clear()
            deck.append(cards)
            return True
        
        if resp == "N":
            return False
        
        print("Invalid input")

def welcome_message()-> str:
    """Prints Welcome Message"""
    print("Welcome to Go Fish!")
    input("Press Enter to play!")
    print(  "Rules: There are two players: You and the computer. " + \
            "Your goal is to make as many 'books' or four of a kind as you can. "+ \
            "Book points are based on the card. " + \
            "Aces are the highest points and 2s are the lowest. " + \
            "Now let's play! Good Luck!")
    input("Press enter to proceed!")

def is_game_over()-> bool:
    """Checks if deck is empty to determine if game is over"""
    if len(deck)>= 1:
        return False
    for card in set(comp):
        if comp.count(card) < 4:
            return False
    for card in set(user):
        if user.count(card) < 4:
            return False 
    return True

def ask_comp():
    """Asks computer to request a card"""
    #REF:https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/
    #How to use random choice
    potential_cards = []
    for card in set(comp):
        if comp.count(card) < 4:
            potential_card.append()
    if len(potential_cards) > 0:
        random_card = potential_cards.choice()
        print("The computer is requesting " + random_card)
    else:
        random_card = comp.choice()     

    if random_card in user:
        print("You have " + random_card + " card and the computer will now take it")
        give_cards(user, comp, random_card)
    else:
        print("You don't have " + random_card + " card and now the computer will Go Fish!")
        go_fish(comp)
        
def ask_user():
    """Asks the user to request a card"""

    invalid = True

    while(invalid):
        
        print("What card would you like? ")
        
        resp = input("Enter something from " + str(user) + ": ")
        resp = resp.upper() 
        
        if resp in user:
            invalid = False
        else:
            print("Invalid response")

    if resp in comp:
        print("Computer has card")
        give_cards(comp, user, resp)
    else:
        print("Computer does not have card")
        go_fish(user)

def score()-> str:
    """Lets player know the score of the game"""
#Comp total referenced before assignment error
    comp_total = 0
    user_total = 0
    
    for card_type in set(comp):
        comp_total = comp_total + point_value[card_type]
    for card_type in set(user):
        user_total = user_total + point_value[card_type]
    if user_total > comp_total:
        print("You won! The computer lost in Go Fish to you!")
    elif user_total < comp_total:
        print("You lost! The computer won Go Fish!")
    else:
        print("You tied with the computer in Go Fish. Congrats!")

def game():
    """starts game"""
    welcome_message()
    deal_cards()
    while is_game_over == False:
        ask_user()
        if is_game_over() == True:
            break
        ask_comp()
        display()

    print("The game is over. Hope you had fun!")
    score()
    game()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the indentation of your code is accurate but it looks like you just defined the functions and didn't actually call any of them in the script.

To do so, on the outermost level of indentation, call your main function, in this case `game()`.